# Quaternion to direction vector - flipping

Tags: mathematics, graphics, vector, ogre, quaternion

I've kinda solved this myself by adapting the Camera::setDirection code from OGRE to work for my need:

Now I have the following code:

```
Vector3 boneDir = getBoneWorldOrientation(mEntity, mHips) * Vector3::UNIT_Z; //mDirection;
Vector3 dir = mCameraTrans->_getDerivedDirection();

Vector3 zAdjustVec = dir;
zAdjustVec.normalise();

Quaternion targetWorldOrientation;

Vector3 xVec = Vector3::UNIT_Y.crossProduct(zAdjustVec);
xVec.normalise();

Vector3 yVec = zAdjustVec.crossProduct(xVec);
yVec.normalise();

targetWorldOrientation.FromAxes(xVec, yVec, zAdjustVec);
```

`mTransform` is basically the SceneNode of the character, I'm multiplying the target orientation with it's inverse orientation to get it to parent/character-space.
`mHips->_setDerivedOrientation(mTransform->_getDerivedOrientation().Inverse() * targetWorldOrientation);`
The above code was taken from OgreCamera.cpp, the setDirection function, the part with the fixed yaw axis.
Now, that works... Sorta, I now get this problem at near-90 degree pitch, the orientation kind of flips to the other side, I've made another video to showcase this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6bdFhW_vtUs

Any ideas on how to fix this ?

I've asked on both the OGRE3D and GameDev.net forums, I'll link to there just in case.

OGRE3D: http://ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=78213
GD.Net: http://www.gamedev.net/topic/644417-vectorquaternion-help-pitch-bone-to-direction-vector/

Comment: In your coordinate system, which direction is down toward the floor?  It is clear your cross product is flipping as you pass by that direction (probably negative `UNITY`), but just to be clear.    The solution probably involves eschewing those absolute unit vectors and maintaining your own reference directions relative to the camera.

Comment: OR! clamp your pitch to +- < 90 degrees.  If you don't pass that axis, no problem occurs, right?

Comment: Yes, pretty much. Thanks a lot for the reply I'm not too good with Vector/Quaternion math. And yes, -UNIT_Y is the downward direction.  I think I'll go with the second option, as I don't need more pitch then that. :)

Comment: You are welcome.  Be sure to come back and post your final solution as an answer.